# Format row based on text length

Tags: excel, text, string-length

I need to sort out one macro. I have table and need to highlight a row with a color, but not the entire row, just from columns A to J when text in one of the cells in column A is longer than 4 digits-letters.

I don't want to use conditional formatting.

Can somebody please advice if it's possible?

Comment: What have you tried already? What is it that stores your table? Where do you want to create a macro?

Comment: Are you talking about MS Excel?

Comment: Yes, about Excel. But let it  be, this web is so cool, that it does not allow me to show you what I have already. Cannot enter code to my message. Never mind, i will go somewhere else. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Can't you edit your own message?

Answer (score 1):

To do so with Conditional Formatting, select ColumnsA-J then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=LEN($A1)>4
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select highlighting OK, OK.